# No PJAX functions work apart from one

Tags: html, ajax, phpbb, phpbb3, pjax

I have a PHPBB forum along with PJAX.

PJAX works well with links however whenever I try use a .pjax function I get an error in firebug, claiming that .pjax is not defined?

Here is what works:

```
pjax.connect('wrap');
```

Here is what doesn't work:

```
$(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container')
$.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-container')
```

and anything that contains .pjax.

I have the pjax/pjax-standalone.min.js file included in my header.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: If you could post a more full code example, or an example elsewhere - I'd be happy to look at it.  Are you per chance calling pjax before it is loaded?

Comment: Hi Joshua, the team and I figured out the issue. I can't remember exactly what we done off the top of our heads. Due to scalability issues we had to dismiss pjax for this project. Thanks for your comment though :)